# DataTables inline editing, how to display the checkbox to checked when the data value is true

Tags: asp.net-core, datatables

I use DataTables 1.10.22 in my ASP MVC Net Core 3.1 project,
I have an inline checkbox, how to display the checkbox to checked when the data value is true?
so, re to my code below, filtered_ds.is_supervisor would be true or false, I expect to have the automatic checkbox checked when filtered_ds.is_supervisor is true, how to accomplish this?

```
 {
    orderable: false,
    data: filtered_ds.is_supervisor,
    render: function (data, type, row, meta) {
    var idx = meta.row;

    if (type === 'display') 
    {
       return `<input type="checkbox" class="editor-is_supervisor" onclick="myfunc(this)" 
       id="${idx} " + (data == true ? 'checked':'') />`;
    }
    return data;
},
className: 'text-center align-middle'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to use:

```
    if (type === 'display')
    {
        if (filtered_ds.is_supervisor)
        {
            return "<input type='checkbox' class='editor-is_supervisor' onclick='myfunc(this)'  id='" + idx + "' checked />";
        } else
        {
            return "<input type='checkbox' class='editor-is_supervisor' onclick='myfunc(this)'  id='" + idx + "' />";
        }
                                   
    }
```